# Change an AT&T iPhone 3G to another provider?

Tags: iphone

How can I change my no-longer under AT&T service iPhone 3G to my new sprint service? Sprint doesn't use sim cards.

Answer (score 5):

You can't.  AT&T and Sprint use incompatible technologies.

Comment: Exactly. The iPhone 3G does not have compatible hardware.

Comment: You can port the number to a sprint iPhone or select a phone that works with spring. AT&T is now unlocking phones, so you should be able to sell your AT&T iPhone for decent money - even in late 2012 and an iPhone 3G.